# Projectivity of analytic $\mathbb{P}^1$ bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-geometry

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a smooth analytic $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle from a complex manifold $X$ to a complex projective manifold $Y$. Is $X$ a projective manifold?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The answer is yes. You can deduce this directly from the Kodaira embedding theorem, considering the tautological line bundle from the $\Bbb P^1$ bundle and the hyperplane class on $Y$. (This is true, more generally, for any analytic $\Bbb P^k$-bundle. It's easiest to see when it is of the form $\Bbb P(E)$ for a holomorphic vector bundle $E$, but Kodaira proved it in general.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Perhaps it is worth you writing a detailed answer, given the state of the present proposed answer?

Comment: @VeryConfused: I think the OP, having made zero effort so far, could make the commitment to work on what I've suggested. I'm not interested in writing a detailed answer at this time.

Comment: @TedShifrin Fair call